# Proof of third isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H<G$ a subgroup of $G$ and $K<H$ a subgroup of $H$. Assume that $[G:K]$ is finite. Then: $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$.

---

In the case where $G$ is finite, the proof is pretty simple using Lagrange theorem and a bit algebra. However, I'm not sure what to do in case $G$ is infinite.

Edit: I have seen the solution in the linked post. I still have one question: In the answer, we define a bijection $\phi:(H\backslash G)\times(K \backslash H) \to K \backslash G \ \ $ by $\ \ \phi(Ha_i,Kb_j)=Kb_ja_i$.

Why is this function well defined?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You also need to have that $H$ has finite index. Then, you can say that $$G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n a_iH $$ and that $$H = \bigcup_{j=1}^m b_jK,$$ and then prove that $$ G = \bigcup_{i,j}a_ib_jK $$ and that all the sets $a_ib_jK$ are distinct.

Comment: Why are $[G:H],[H:K]$ finite? (formally)

Comment: Well, your hypothesis has $[G:H]$ finite, and you also need to have $K$ with finite index.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $[G:K]$ is finite (I edited the question)